# E: Package '<any package>' has no installation candidate

Tags: apt

I am unable to `apt-get install` any packages because `E: Package '<package name>' has no installation candidate`.  Unlike the other similarly named questions, I have not been able to get any packages to work due to the same error.  apt is still able to list repositories.  I have updated, upgraded, rebooted, and repeated after my attempts at fixing sources.list, but nothing has worked.

Running

```
$ find /etc/apt/ -path *.list | xargs cat
```

Produces

```
1  #------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
2  #                   OFFICIAL DEBIAN REPOS                    
3  #------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
4  
5  ###### Debian Main Repos
6  deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ jessie main contrib non-free 
7  deb-src http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ jessie main contrib non-free 
8 
9  ###### Debian Update Repos
10 deb http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main contrib non-free 
11 deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ jessie-proposed-updates main contrib non-free 
12 deb-src http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main contrib non-free 
13 deb-src http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ jessie-proposed-updates main contrib non-free 
14 
15 
16 deb http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/ jessie main ui
17 # Uncomment line below then 'apt-get update' to enable 'apt-get source'
18 deb-src http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/ jessie main ui
19 deb https://dev2day.de/pms/ jessie main
20 deb http://dl.bintray.com/openhab/apt-repo stable main
```

Comment: did you do `sudo apt-get update` first :)

Comment: Yes. No errors.

Comment: You're making a [FrankenDebian](https://wiki.debian.org/DontBreakDebian#Don.27t_make_a_FrankenDebian) potentially there.  You've got two repositories listed above that can make a mess by offering conflicting versions of the same packaging in the same suite.  The conflict exist between the debian.org lines and the raspberrypi.org lines.  You'll need to pick repositories that don't offer up the same thing as each other so that installation candidates can be chosen.

Comment: @StephenMichaelKellat I just added line numbers.  Which ones exactly do I delete? I don't want to potentially make things worse by misunderstanding.

Comment: @twinlakes Put hash marks at the start of 16 & 18, run apt update, and then see if you're able to install.  If so I'll need to convert this colloquy into an answer.  If no, remove the hash marks from 16 & 18, place hash marks at 6 10 11, and try again.

Comment: @StephenMichaelKellat no luck :( Should I just resolve to reimaging my pi?

Comment: @twinlakes The big question is what you had in the first place.  Don't commingle repositories that have overlapping package versions if you reload.